# Kotlin generics not being cast correctly

Tags: generics, kotlin, casting

I have an abstract class (`MessageHandlerAdapter`) that takes in a generic type (`P`) and is then used to type the value passed into one of its functions:

```
abstract class MessageHandlerAdapter<in P : Any> {
    abstract fun canHandle(): MessageType
    abstract fun handle(payload: P)
}
```

If I use it with `List<MessageHandlerAdapter<*>>`, I get the error message `Out-projected type 'MessageHandlerAdapter<*>' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun handle(payload: P): Unit defined in MessageHandlerAdapter'` on the use of `strategy.handle(message.payload)`:

```
class MessageHandlerStrategy(
    private val messageHandlers: List<MessageHandlerAdapter<*>>
) {
    private val strategies = messageHandlers.map { Pair(it.canHandle(), it) }.toMap()

    fun handle(message: Message<Any>) {
        val strategy = strategies[message.type]
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException>(IllegalArgumentException("No MessageHandler for message of type ${message.type}"))

        strategy.handle(message.payload)
    }
}
```

However, if I use it with `List<MessageHandlerAdapter<Any>>`, I get the error message `Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: required: List<MessageHandlerAdapter<Any>>found: List<MessageHandlerAdapter<*>>` on the list I'm trying to pass in:

```
lateinit var stringHandler: MessageHandlerAdapter<String>
lateinit var  intHandler: MessageHandlerAdapter<Int>
val messageHandlerStrategy = MessageHandlerStrategy(listOf(stringHandler, intHandler))

class MessageHandlerStrategy(
    private val messageHandlers: List<MessageHandlerAdapter<Any>>
) {
    private val strategies = messageHandlers.map { Pair(it.canHandle(), it) }.toMap()

    fun handle(message: Message<Any>) {
        val strategy = strategies[message.type]
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException>(IllegalArgumentException("No MessageHandler for message of type ${message.type}"))

        strategy.handle(message.payload)
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing the signature of `MessageHandlerAdapter`  to `abstract class MessageHandlerAdapter<P : Any> {...` but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `MessageHandlerAdapter`s of different types, your list has to use star projection `<*>`, but this makes the objects coming out of your list useless for calling any function that takes the type as an argument. You will have to cast your retrieved adapter to be able to call a typed function on it.

First I would eliminate the MessageType class and just use the KClass of the payload type to simplify how we deal with it and remove the possibility of creating a Message with mismatched MessageType and payload type:

```
abstract class MessageHandlerAdapter<P : Any>(val payloadType: KClass<P>) {
    abstract fun handle(payload: P)
}

// Just an example, don't know what your Message class has
data class Message<P : Any>(val payloadType: KClass<P>, val payload: P)
```

Then the Message's `payloadType` property is available for easy checking and cast.

In your strategy class you can cast your `MessageHandlerAdapter<*>` to a `MessageHandlerAdapter<P>` and know that it's safe to do so because you retrieved it via its `payloadType` which must be the same as its generic type.

Unfortunately, the compiler isn't sophisticated enough to know this even if you use `try/catch`, so you will get an unchecked cast warning. You can use `@Suppress` to hide the warning.

The `handle` function also needs a generic Message type or  you would only be able to pass in `Message<Any>`s.

```
class MessageHandlerStrategy(
    private val messageHandlers: List<MessageHandlerAdapter<*>>
) {

    fun <P : Any> handle(message: Message<P>) {
        val strategy = messageHandlers.find { it.payloadType == message.payloadType }
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("No MessageHandler for message of type ${message.payloadType}")

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        (strategy as MessageHandlerAdapter<Any>).handle(message.payload)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The message is `interface Message<out P : Any> { val payload: P, val type: MessageType }`. The `MessageType` is just an enum to define what the message is (update X, perform action Y, etc.). At the end of the day, what I'm getting from your response is that we have to do some kind of casting. I'm just surprised that in Java one could apply `MessageHandler<Object>` and it's happy, but in Kotlin, there isn't an equivalent. I understand why, just takes some getting used to I guess.